# com.google.api.gax.grpc.ApiException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

Tags: google-cloud-vision

Recently,I use google cloud vision api for detecting image label ,follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries)
,I  set up the  credentials for my application to authenticate its identity to the service and obtain authorization to perform task,then follow the API Documentation ,write code like this:

```
ImageAnnotatorClient vision= ImageAnnotatorClient.create();
        ByteString imgBytes = ByteString.readFrom(new FileInputStream("my_image_path.jpg"));
        List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<AnnotateImageRequest>();
        Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(imgBytes).build();

         Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Type.LABEL_DETECTION).build();
         AnnotateImageRequest request = AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder()
                    .addFeatures(feat)
                    .setImage(img)
                    .build();
                requests.add(request);
                BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = vision.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
                List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();

                for (AnnotateImageResponse res : responses) {
                    if (res.hasError()) {
                      System.out.printf("Error: %s\n", res.getError().getMessage());
                      return;
                    }
                    for (EntityAnnotation annotation : res.getLabelAnnotationsList()) {
                        annotation.getAllFields().forEach((k, v)->System.out.printf("%s : %s\n", k, v.toString()));
                      }
                }
```

I get error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.gax.grpc.ApiException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ExceptionTransformingCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(ExceptionTransformingCallable.java:109)
    at com.google.api.gax.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:52)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1310)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:466)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:442)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:481)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:398)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:513)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:52)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:545)
    ... 13 more
```

why?